# Using Windows environmental variables in file URI scheme

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, uri

Can we use environmental variables, such %userprofile% or %appdata%, in a path, in a file URI scheme, from a browser (or at least a Chrome browser)?

Something like

```
file:///%userprofile%/Documents/someFile.html
```

Im writing a Chrome extension that analizes Chrome Preferences JSON file, to detect suspicious malware activity.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.  And I tried a lot of alternatives, without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Chrome does not recognize environment variables in URL's/URI's.

In [the URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-11), `%` is reserved for Percent-Encoding of characters.

Comment: What about %OS%, %VERSION% or even %GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY% variables that you can find in firefox for example?